# Constructors using super AND instance variables

Tags: java, oop, constructor, super

I'm learning Java using Sams Teach Yourself Java in 21 days (btw this is taking me much longer than 21 days).  In chapter 5, the final exercise asks me to create a class FourDPoint which is a subclass of Point.  I did this, but had an interesting result.  The first time I did the exercise this was my code:

```
import java.awt.Point;

class FourDPoint extends Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int t;

    FourDPoint(int x, int y, int z, int t){
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        FourDPoint fp = new FourDPoint(5, 5, 10, 10);
        System.out.println("x is " + fp.x);
        System.out.println("y is " + fp.y);
        System.out.println("z is " + fp.z);
        System.out.println("t is " + fp.t);
    }
}
```

The result: x is 0, y is 0, z is 10, y is 10.

I changed my code by eliminating the intitilized x and y, which gave me the correct answer.  My question: why did I get x is 0 and y is 0?  Do the intitiaized x and y take precedence over the super(x, y)?

Answer (score 7):

[This is what we call **hiding**.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) Assuming your class `Point` also declares two instance variables named `x` and `y`, those are the ones you are setting with

```
super(x, y);
```

However, when you reference

```
System.out.println("x is " + fp.x);
System.out.println("y is " + fp.y);
```

you are referring to the members declared in `FourDPoint`. Those haven't been initialized by you, so they default to 0.

On a related note, polymorphism does not apply to instance variables. Instead, the member is resolved according to the type of the reference on which you accessed it.

So

```
FourDPoint fp = ...;
fp.x;
```

`fp.x` would refer to the `x` member declared in `FourDPoint`. But

```
FourDPoint fp = ...;
fp.x;
((Point) fp).x;
```

`((Point) fp).x;` would refer to the `x` member declared in `Point`.

Answer (score 5):

In your subclass, you shadow Points x and y variables with your own. To fix this, you can either remove your x and y (You don't use them) or reference Points ones using `super.x` and `super.y`

When you call super() in the constructor, Point sets its x and y fields. You created an x and y yourself that get defaulted to 0. So when you reference fp.x and fp.y, you will always get your ones (which are always 0)

Answer (score 5):

Your class `FourDPoint` contains local members that shadow the super Point `x` and `y`, comment out these two lines -

```
// int x;
// int y;
```

Answer (score 3):

You never set the values of `x` and `y` to something, so they will always return 0.

Yes, you call the super constructor but this doesn't matter: even if there are variables `x` and `y` in `Point`, they are hidden by the variables named the same in `FourDPoint`.

Not to mention that the variables in `Point` should have been `protected` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is like this: Parent's members are initialized, parents constructor is called, your class members are initialized (primitives are set to 0) your class constructor's code executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they take precedence because you overwrote them. Simple as that.